# How to prevent this language flag changing when I press F5?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I select Korean from the language dropdown everything is good, the flag changes, except when I F5.. the flag keeps reverting to English instead of Korean. How to make it stay whatever is selected after F5? Thanks

I've separated the header part here:
header.html:

```
<div class="logo">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo_white.svg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
</div>

<nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link scrollto " href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link scrollto " href="research.html">Research</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link " href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#footer">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span><img id="flags" src="assets/img/flags/en.svg" class="flags" alt="English">
      </span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" data-code="zh"><span><img src="assets/img/flags/zh.svg" class="flags" alt="Chinese"> Chinese - 中文</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-code="ja"><span><img src="assets/img/flags/ja.svg" class="flags" alt="Japanese"> Japanese - 日本語</span></a></li>
          <li onclick="setLanguagePreference('en', 'assets/img/flags/en.svg'); updateLanguage();"><a href="#"><span><img src="assets/img/flags/en.svg" class="flags" alt="English"> English - US</span></a></li>
          <li onclick="setLanguagePreference('ko', 'assets/img/flags/ko.svg'); updateLanguage();"><a href="#"><span><img src="assets/img/flags/ko.svg" class="flags" alt="Korean"> Korean - 중국어</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
</nav>
```

and the main index is here:
index.html:

````
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#includedContent").load("header.html");
            });
        </script>

</head>
<body>
etc...
<h1 id="description">Show English Text</h1>
</body>

<script>
  // Function to set the language preference and update the flag
  function setLanguagePreference(language, flagSrc) {
    // Use localStorage to store the selected language
    localStorage.setItem('selectedLanguage', language);
    // Update the flag image source
    document.getElementById('flags').src = flagSrc;
    // Update the language content
    updateLanguage();
  }

  // Function to get the language preference
  function getLanguagePreference() {
    // Retrieve the selected language from localStorage
    const selectedLanguage = localStorage.getItem('selectedLanguage');
    // If no language is selected, default to English
    return selectedLanguage ? selectedLanguage : 'en';
  }

  // Function to update the language based on the user's preference
  function updateLanguage() {
    const selectedLanguage = getLanguagePreference();
    if (selectedLanguage === 'ko') {
      // Set the description or content to Korean
      document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = "Show Korean Text";
      // You can similarly update other page content based on the language here.
    } else {
      // Set the description or content to English
      document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = "Show English Text";
      // You can similarly update other page content based on the language here.
    }
  }

  // Call the updateLanguage function when the page loads
  window.addEventListener('load', updateLanguage);
</script>```
````

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. Do you get any errors in the browser *developer* tools console?

Comment: @logeshsankar the code uses localStorage

Comment: For errors in the browser developer tools console I get: Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://0.0.0.0:8000/jquery.js”. index.html:33:26
Source map error: Error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: http://0.0.0.0:8000/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
Source Map URL: bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map

Comment: I'm using python -m http.server for this to test locally, before uploading to server (I havent tested on server yet)

Comment: The F5 key is the refresh key. If you press F5 on your browser, the HTML file will refresh. If you want to save the response after refresh, you should save it locally or on an API.

Comment: `Loading failed for the <script>` well, fix that

Comment: @PortMe - do you know what `localStorage` is?

Comment: I noticed the flag reverts to english on navlink click to product.html when I click also, but <h1> is fine and shown Korean text